# Not able to execute success function in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to fix this code from the past few hours but no success! Not able to figure out what went wrong. This code should give a javascript alert "hi" but nothing happens!

```
  $("button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://rhymebrain.com/talk?function=getRhymes&word=hello",
                dataType: "json",
                success: processJSON
              }); 

        function processJSON(json) {
             alert("hi");
          });
        }               
   });
```

Comment: Look in your browsers developer tools console - you will have an error if that is your exact code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I formatted your code in the Original post and the mistake was you had a additional `});` in your code.. So just remove that and it should be fine. see below

```
    $("button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://rhymebrain.com/talk?function=getRhymes&word=hello",
                dataType: "json",
                success: processJSON
              }); 

        function processJSON(json) {
             alert("hi");
          //});  <-- remove this 
        }               
   });
```

Comment: @Noob_RAM If you have found a solution from anybody's answer in this thread it would be nice if you can mark it as answer, As people spent there time trying to get you a solution. If none of them helps then you can place your problem in the comments and surely they will show up to resolve it further.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.   Dont't write any function inside $.ajax

```
$("button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://rhymebrain.com/talk?function=getRhymes&word=hello",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: processJSON,
                    failure: failureFunction
                }); 
    });


    function processJSON(json) {
        alert("hi");
    });
```

Comment: why? it's perfectly fine to have it within the click function

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes we can but it should not be done that way I suppose...Correct me I am going wrong..

Comment: Why shouldn't it be within the click callback?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your function outside $.ajax

```
$("button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://rhymebrain.com/talk?function=getRhymes&word=hello",
                dataType: "json",
                success: processJSON,
                failure: failureFunction
            }); 
     function processJSON(json) {
        alert("hi");
     });
});
```

Comment: it can be within click

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line:

```
    alert("hi");
});//remove this
```